Unity Collision between Box Collider 2D and Tilemap Collider 2D not working
For practice I want to have an island surrounded by water.
Where I can move freely on the island and use water as a "wall" to block movement in water.
Thats the grid map I build:
Land(green) and water(blue) are on separate layers:

The white square is the "player"
I literally tried the whole day to get it working. I know it should but I can't tell why.
Here are some screenshots of my settings:
Image of the settings of the water tilemap

Image of the settings of the player sprite

I've watched tons of tutorials and was told that there will be green grid lines where the collision boxes are.
I don't see those either

Unity version 2022.3.28f1
I tried reordering the components on the player sprite and the grid
For the player movement I use the velocity parameter on the rigidbody

you dont need a rigidbody if its not moving..  however, ive not made anything in 2d other than simple likes soduku and gems type games so never needed to do  blocking, however, there are often changes as unity versions improve, you'd need to check on a similar major version as to what the correct way is

@BugFinder, the rigidbody comes automatically when adding the composite collider and I can't remove it unless I remove the composite collider as well. Because it's a non-moving object I set to static

Is the water tilemap surrounding the green part, or is it just a big rectangle with land on top?

@Cyclone6664 it is a surrounding tilemap

My mistake was to leave the collider type of my water tiles to 'sprite'.
When changing it to 'grid' my collisions worked as they should.
